# Vscode #include errors detected. Please update your includePath on MacOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, include-path

I have recently updated my mac and have been having issues running C++ files ever since. On every include statement within my project I get this error message `#include errors detected. Please update your includePath.` I am unaware of what to include in my `includePath`. I have seen examples for Ubuntu and Windows but not mac.

Here is `c_cpp_properties.json` file that holds my configurations

```
{

"configurations": [
{
  "name": "Mac",
  "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/usr/lib/**"],
  "defines": [],
  "macFrameworkPath": ["/System/Library/Frameworks", "/Library/Frameworks"],
  "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
  "cStandard": "c11",
  "cppStandard": "c++17",
  "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
}
],
"version": 4

}
```

Comment: You need to update the `includePath` to point to the proper location of the files that aren't being `#include`d correctly. You'd do so just like in Ubuntu, except using the location of the files on your own machine instead.

Comment: Where are the header files located on a mac?

Comment: You can't look on your own computer to find out where a header file is located, when you have the exact name of the file already?